# I have never seen this notation $\mathbb{P}(\{z^i\}\times Z^{-i})$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{z^{-i}\}\times Z^i)$ in my life.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, notation

$\textit{Definition:}$ Suppose that I=$\{1,2,...,N\}$ is a finite set. Given a collection $(Z^i)_{i\in I}$ of sets, $Z$ represents $\Pi_{i}Z^i$, and $Z^{-i}$ denotes $\Pi_{j\neq i}Z^j$.  Similarly, $z^i$ and $z^{-i}$ are the canonical projections of $z\in Z$ on $Z^i$ and $Z^{-i}$. Given a topological set $W$, $\Delta(W)$ denotes the set of regular probability measures over the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on W. If $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure, $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}$ represents the expectation operator over $\mathbb{P}$. For $\mathbb{P} \in \Delta(Z)$ where $Z =\Pi_iZ^i$, $\mathbb{P}(z^i)$ and $\mathbb{P}(z^{-i})$ stand for $\mathbb{P}(\{z^i\}\times Z^{-i})$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{z^{-i}\}\times Z^i)$ respectively.

$\textit{Question:}$ I have never seen the notation $\mathbb{P}(\{z^i\}\times Z^{-i})$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{z^{-i}\}\times Z^i)$ in my life. Does this mean that $\mathbb{P}(\{z^i\}\times Z^{-i})=\mathbb{P}(z^1,z^2,...,z^I)$?

Comment: It just means the Cartesian product of the set $Z^i$ and the singleton set $\{z^i\}$. They are using superscript notation for index in the given definition, as is similarly done in tensor analysis.

Comment: I have no idea about tensor analysis :P but the Cartesian product means that $\{z^i\}\times Z^{-i}=\{z^i\}\times(z^1,z^2,...,z^{i-1},z^{i+1},...,z^I)\underbrace{=}_{?}(z^1,z^2,...,z^{i-1},z^i,z^{i+1},...,z^I)$... Am I right?

Comment: No. Try seeing with a simple example: $I:=\{1,2\}$ and $(Z^i)_{i\in I}:=(\{x,y\},\{u,v\})$. By the definition, $Z=Z^1\times Z^2=\{(x,u),(x,v),(y,u),(y,v)\}$ and $Z^{-1}=Z^2,~Z^{-2}=Z^1$. For some element $z\in Z$, $z^i$ denotes the canonical projection on $Z^i$, ie, the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ component of $z$. Can you work out now what are the Cartesian products, say, $\{z^1\}\times Z^1$ and $\{z^1\}\times Z^{-1}$ are, with say, $z=(x,u)\in Z$?

Comment: ok this is clear! Thanks! @Prasun Biswas let me check your question

Comment: A final point: The projections $z^{-i}$ are not single components when $|I|\gt 2$. For example, say $Z=\{a,b\}\times\{x,y\}\times\{u,v\}$ and $z=(a,x,u)\in Z$. Then, while $z^i$'s are simply the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ component of $z$ for positive $i$, $z^{-i}$'s are 2-tuples, eg., $z^1=a$ and $z^{-1}=(x,u)$

Comment: $Z^1=\{x,y\}$ and $Z^{-1}=\{u,v\}$, since $z=(\underbrace{x}_{z^1},\underbrace{u}_{z^2})\in Z$, then 
$$\{z^1\}\times Z^1= \{(x,x), (x,y)\}$$ and
$$\{z^1\}\times Z^{-1}= \{(x,u), (x,v)\}$$... If I am not mistaken

Comment: Yes, that is correct. :) Try a few more examples, like the one I gave in my last comment with $I=\{1,2,3\}$ and you'll get a feel for how it looks in the general case.

Comment: Similarly if $|I|$=3 and $Z=\{a,b\}\times\{x,y\}\times\{u,v\}$ and $Z^1=\{a,b\}$ then 
$$\{z^1\}\times Z^1=\{(a,a),(a,b\}$$
$$\{z^{-1}\}\times Z^1=\{(x,a),(x,b),(u,a),(u,b)\}$$
Also $Z^{-1}=\{(x,u),(x,v),(y,u),(y,v)\}$ and $z^{-1}=(x,u)$
$$\{z^{-1}\}\times Z^{-1}=\{(x,x,u),(x,x,v),(x,y,v),(x,y,v),(u,x,u),(u,x,v),(u,y,u),(u,y,v)\}$$

Comment: @Prasun Biswas I think this is the case if you check the example above

Comment: The singleton set $\{z^{-1}\}=\{(x,u)\}$ is not the same as the two element set $\{x,u\}$, do you see the error in your last comment?

Comment: @Prasun Biswas Not exaclty...what's wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128627/discussion-between-prasun-biswas-and-hunger-learn).

Comment: $\{(x,u)\}\times \{a,b\}=\{((x,u),a),((x,u),b)\}\ne\{x,u\}\times \{a,b\}= \{(x,a),(x,b),(u,a),(u,b)\}$

Comment: So $\{z^{-1}\}\times Z^{-1}=\{((x,u),(x,u)),((x,u),(x,v)),((x,u),(y,u)),((x,u),(y,v))\}$ ... right? @Prasun Biswas

Comment: @Matthew Leingang sorry for not being so creative in headlines :P but if you have to say something else about the question not being a question, I would appreciate this

Comment: Your question is: What does $\{z^i\} \times Z^{-i}$ mean?